# sox equivalent of silence removal in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

If I have an audio file in .wav format, I can run `sox` on it as follows :
`sox in.wav out6.wav silence -l 1 0.1 1% -1 2.0 1%` and this command works   really really well for removing silence.

Is there some similar command that I can use in ffmpeg?

At the moment, I'm converting from .mp4 to .wav by doing
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.wav`

and then doing the sox silence removal command.

What I want to do is, not shorten the audio but keep the silenced out regions in the audio as  empty portions/pauses.

Answer (score 0):

## [`silenceremove`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#silenceremove)

This filer discards samples below a threshold (in deciBels), silence period can be shrinked to a certain interval.

From the **FFmpeg** manual:

> The following example shows how this filter can be used to start a recording that does not contain the delay at the start which usually occurs between pressing the record button and the start of the performance:
>
> ```bsh
> ffmpeg in.mp4 -filter:a "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=5:start_threshold=0.02" out.mp4
> ```